# Как решить задачу "обратного" рюкзака в c++?

Tags: c++, динамическое-программирование

Ввод данных точно также как в рюкзаке, только суммарный вес должен быть таким, что при добавлении любого другого объекта в оптимальное множество, вес должен превосходить заданный W, а стоимость объектов должна быть минимальной

Comment: Что есть рюкзак? и о каком весе и стоимости речь? Нашествие клонов? :)

Comment: Да, дополните пожалуйста задачу.

Comment: Понятно, что подразумевается эта [задача](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_о_ранце).

Comment: Можно свести к классической задаче, приписав "-" к стоимости предметов.